# Problems to test a repository code (Node JS, webpack)

Tags: node.js, github, web-applications, webpack

The repository is the next: https://github.com/googlecreativelab/chrome-music-lab

I downloaded it but I am not able to "run" on my computer. I am trying to run the "chords" folder, following the readme.md steps.

Steps followed:

1) Download ZIP project from repository (and unzip it).

2) Navigate with node command prompt to the directory of the unzipped project.

3) Execute this commands:

"npm install"

"npm install webpack" (it seemed right)

"webpack -p" (it returned: 
The CLI moved into a separate package: webpack-cli.
Please install 'webpack-cli' in addition to webpack itself to use the CLI.
-> When using npm: npm install webpack-cli -D
-> When using yarn: yarn add webpack-cli -D)

I have been researched a lot but I am completely lost on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I detected the problem and I found the solution. It was the version of webpack weren't the correct (other versions produced different errors), so the commands I had to execute were:

1) npm install webpack@1.15.0 -D -g

2) npm install -D -g

3) webpack [-p]

Now, I have the "build" folder and I can use the different modules to test "chords" part of this application.